# add text to plot or legend for second axis only R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I very nearly have the plot that I want so I think this will be an easy fix for someone more R savvy than myself

```
Sample_ID <- c("P1014B", "P1014F", "P1036A", "P1036B", "P1036C", "P1036D", "P1036E", "P1036F")
`CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)` <- c(2677, 1021, 870, 6831, 1324, 4175, 1370, 875)
`CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)` <- c(0.101, 1.000, 1.000, 0.000, 1.000, 0.036, 1.000, 1.000)
contam_reads <- data.frame(Sample_ID, `CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`, `CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)`, check.names = FALSE)
```

I have a plot that is very near to what I want:

```
cols = c("P-value upper Limit" = "black","Contam. score upper limit" = "red")

ggplot(contam_reads[-c(1,2),], aes(x=Sample_ID, y=`CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`))  + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="cyan4") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=contam_reads$`CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`[1]), col = cols[2], size = 1.5, linetype=2) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=contam_reads$`CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)`[1]*10000), col = cols[1], size = 1, linetype=2) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Sample_ID, y=`CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)`* 10000),stat="identity",color="red", size = 1.5, show.legend = T) +
  labs(title= "DNA Library QC Metrics for Contamination",
       x="Sample ID",y="Contamination Score") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~./10000,name="P-value", breaks = seq(0,1,0.1))) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "cyan4",size=15),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "cyan4"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red")
  ) +    
  scale_colour_manual(values=cols)
```

[image: help]

I can't get the legend to be a line and not dots, and I can't get the first dot in the legend to turn black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix your legend by mapping on aesthetics, i.e. instead of setting colors for the `hline`s as arguments map on the `color` aes and set `show.legend=FALSE` for `geom_point` to show just the lines. To this end I also use the `data` argument to pass just the first line of the dataset to the `hline`s.

Note 1: I added a named vector with labels for your scores and values. Also as names I use abbreviations for both the labels and color vector which makes it much easier to refer to a specific value in the ggplot code and makes the code easier to read.

Note 2: In my plot the colors for the lines are swapped which is right if p-values should be "red" and scores "black". Perhaps you confused that which could easily happen if one uses e.g. `cols[1]` to refer to colors.

```r
cols <- c("pval" = "red", "score" = "black")
labels <- c("pval" = "P-value upper Limit", "score" = "Contam. score upper limit")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(contam_reads[-c(1, 2), ], aes(x = Sample_ID, y = `CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "cyan4") +
  geom_hline(
    data = contam_reads[1, ],
    aes(yintercept = `CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`, color = "score"),
    size = 1.5, linetype = 2
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    data = contam_reads[1, ],
    aes(yintercept = `CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)` * 10000, color = "pval"),
    size = 1, linetype = 2
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sample_ID, y = `CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)` * 10000, color = "pval"),
    stat = "identity", size = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "DNA Library QC Metrics for Contamination",
    x = "Sample ID", y = "Contamination Score",
    color = NULL
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 10000, name = "P-value", breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "cyan4", size = 15),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "cyan4"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red")
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols, labels = labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan, I don't quite understand what the mapping on aesthetics means or works or exactly how the scale_colour_manual works. (e.g. If I plot section by section, up to and including the first geom_hline, the line comes out as red, and up to the second geom_hline, the line comes out as turquoise then it all comes together when the last line is run).  Is the 'color = "score" in the first geom_hline labelling the legend (and is nothing to do with colour???)

Comment: In general when we "map on aesthetics" we tell ggplot2 how we want a data column to be displayed, i.e. whether we want it on the x or y axis or displayed as different colors. Additionally when we map on aes we (automatically) get a legend. This is not the case when you set the color as an argument, i.e. outside of `aes()`. Moreover when we do something like `color="score"` we map a column with a constant value of "score" on the color aes. ggplot2 will then automatically pick a color for this value and display in the legend.

Comment: To override the ggplot2 color choice we use `scale_color_manual` to assign our desired colors and to set desired labels, e.g `c("pval" = "red", "score" = "black")`  means to assign a color "black" to the value "score".